# Hash with delete

Tags: ruby

Why does this:

```
elements = Hash.new()
elements[100] = "a"
elements[200] = "b"
elements[300] = "c"
elements[400] = "d"

print "Count: ", elements.count(), 

elements.delete(100)

print "Count: ", elements.count(),
```

return this:

```
Count: 4
Count: 3
```

I wonder why that wouldn't return anything except the value `100`.

Comment: Why are you expecting it to "return" any elements at all? The code is perfectly sensible, but I can't figure out what your problem is.

Comment: I was thinking that the delete completely deleted the 100, 200, 300, and 400 and only returned 3 & 4.

Comment: Empty hashes are usually initialized via `elements = {}` and you can omit the empty parentheses, i.e. you can just write `elements.count`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as expected.

You are printing the count for your `elements` hash which is `4` at the beginning, then you are deleing one element using: `elements.delete(100)` then printing the count again, which is `3` now.

See this way to understand what's going on with your `elements` hash:

```
elements = Hash.new()
elements[100] = "a"
elements[200] = "b"
elements[300] = "c"
elements[400] = "d"

puts "elements: #{elements.inspect}"
puts "Count: #{elements.count()}"
elements.delete(100)
puts "elements: #{elements.inspect}"
puts "Count: #{elements.count()}"

# > elements: {100=>"a", 200=>"b", 300=>"c", 400=>"d"}
# > Count: 4
# > elements: {200=>"b", 300=>"c", 400=>"d"}
# > Count: 3
```

Comment: Oooooh!!!! I get it! So it returns the first hash and then returns the hash with the delete, I was thinking that the return was that it was only returning 3 & 4. Thank you!